# Update spinner data

Tags: android, spinner

I have a spinner with some data, but when I add a new data, the spinner does not take the new data and only show the old data..

Anyone know how to refresh the data from the spinner?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on your adapter. This method notifies a `View` to refresh itself.